# Posts Appearing on "Hot Network Questions" List. Let's make them good!

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Alright, as private beta is over, questions of the site (which get lots of activity) will now start showing in the Hot Network Questions list. Which means, they will have a lot of audience, almost the entire SE userbase.

This is a very viable tool to expand the site, attract more users and ultimately generate more content for the site.

We need to make sure that when users find this site through that list, it's a good one. This can be done by improving overall *appearance* of the post of really good questions.

By appearance, I mean, it is grammatically correct, simple and interesting.

Questions like this are often pretty simple and easy to understand by everyone, so help promote these questions. If you see a question making that list, make sure it is in top shape and easy to understand.

Remember, the Hot Question list generates a lot of visits to the site making it more popular and helping it graduate sooner.

Please give your thoughts etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with this. Today, about 2-3 post made it to the Hot Network Questions list.

The only thing which bugs me at the current stage is the sites scope which isn't that strong and hence we are experiencing a bit load of off-topic content.

Examples of questions *(Eligible to be closed)* posted after the site entered private beta mode :-

- [What is the base of Hindu?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/655/) (Broad, Unclear)
- [Why is it best if we light ghee lamp in the house while praying?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/647/) *(Wants scientific reason)*
- [What is the significance of “Akhanda Deepak” while doing puja?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/649/) *(almost a duplicate to the above question)*
- [Who and What is Hindu?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/645/) *(Too Broad)*
- [Jain non-violence](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/622/) *(Off-Topic)*

So I would like to suggest the users to read the questions on meta and than start posting your answers.

Posts which will be useful for getting started :-

- [How does a new user get started on Hinduism SE?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33/)
- [List of posts tagged with **scope**](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:124%20%5Bscope%5D)

I hope that helps us get less low quality post.

Comment: hehe, just wait until you or someone becomes a mod, all these problems would be vanished then! Thats why I wanted to hold mod elections before public beta starts. Anyways...

Comment: @AwalGarg till then we have close votes...