# Are Buddha's origin and life going to be a nod to cross religious questions?

Tags: discussion, scope

We know Gautama Buddha was born as a Hindu religion and also talked about topics in Hinduism including Vedas, caste system and many more. He is also predicted as an incarnation of Vishnu in the Puranas.

Not only this, since Buddhism was prevalent during medeival times, many Hindu philosophers criticized Buddhism in their texts.

Showing this a reason, we are getting some questions which ask about Buddha's opinion on a Hindu topic. There was also a question which asks about flaws in Buddhism.

Now we have to look at our meta to check what we have discussed already about other religions.

From [How does a new user get started on Hinduism SE?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/45/5212)

> **Avoid asking cross religion questions**, I am just highlighting this out in bold because we want to avoid religion wars here, don't compare any other religion with Hinduism, stick to the topic, I would not post any examples for this, I hope people understand. Don't compare religions on good/bad parts, don't post questions if you've heard some cross religion rumors

Buddhism is definitely a different religion. There's a different site for it where there are experts and followers of that religion. Perhaps they can answer better about Buddhism rather than our simple block quote of some book or our speculations. Even if one is an expert at Buddhism or other religions, there are other places to write about them. Our site is not a correct place to write about those religions. This is what I feel but these questions.

Some examples of cross religious questions:

- [What's the difference between Dvaita and the Abrahamic faiths?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/37687/5212)
- [According to Hindu philosophy, what are the flaws in Buddha's teachings?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/37231/5212)
- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/37705/5212 (for 2k users)

Treatment of these questions is different. I don't know why. Some are closed, some are reopened with edits (Classical "According to Hindu" method), some are deleted. But all have same question i.e., they ask about other religions. They have [tag: other-religions].

I raised this question because there seems to be a support to those questions (by upvotes and not close voting, leaving open in review) and answers which quote other religions and provide cross religious claims against our policy.

What do you think? How should we deal questions which ask about Buddhism and cross religious questions?

Or should we rule out this faq and allow questions which ask cross religious questions on Buddha and Buddhism due to above reasons (supporting questions)?

The [buddhism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buddhism) and [other-religions](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/other-religions) were useless for finding scope of questions on those topics on our site.

> For questions about how Buddhism relates to Hinduism. See also Buddhism.SE

and

> Other Religions-Which are different from Hinduism

(Everyone knows other religions on our site means religions are not Hinduism. I wonder what exactly is the tag excerpt wanted to convey about the tag).

This is not only limited to questions but to answers too. There have been answers quote other religious texts and allude them to Hinduism and which quote Hinduism texts and speculate them to be other religious figures. Just for example,

1. Mohammad is the Kalki Avatar predicted
2. Adam and Eve story has roots in the Vedas. Christianity took inspiration from that text.

Other rumours popular about other religious figures.

If you think this last paragraph would be better as a new discussion, let me know in comments.