# Was my question unfairly deleted?

Tags: discussion

[My question comparing the God of Hinduism to the God of the Abrahamic religions](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/37705/is-the-god-of-the-abrahamic-religions-the-same-as-the-brahman-of-hinduism) was deleted as off-topic:

> This question does not appear to be about Hindu religion, within the scope defined in the help center.

[This question comparing Dvaita to the Abrahamic religions](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/37687/whats-the-difference-between-dvaita-and-the-abrahamic-faiths) has currently received 4 off-topic close votes.

However, questions which compare Hinduism to other religions [are actually on topic according to this answer](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/199/11726).

We even have an "other-religions" tag.

Moreover, some users have gotten offended at me saying that Islam is an asuric religion, but that shouldn't warrant a close vote becase because Hindu scripture says religions of that kind are asuric/tamasic.

Comment: A chaotic situation is prevailing in this site.  With moderators remaining dormant, senior members being biased, what justice can be expected in this site?

Comment: And this question is allowed  (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/1980/3869)

Comment: You question don't fall under the domain of Indian philosophies. Abrahamic  religions are not part of Sanatana Dharam. Hence, it is very difficult, if not impossible, to furnish you with expert level answer. So, it is justified to delete you question.

Comment: If  a site about religion/spirituality is dominated by sceptics this is what is going to happen. Previously we used to have religious minded and knowledgeable users but now most of them are inactive due to severely poor quality of posts or may be due to other reasons. And, different types of sceptics are dominating the site at present. @srimannarayanakv Mods not doing their job is not the reason.

Comment: The moderators are definitely dormant, apart from being biased, in this site.  I have observed the same in 2015 and still have been observing the same now also @Rickross

Comment: That may have been the case in 2015 and that's 5 years ago. Not the same now, when I hv joined and sometime after that there was only one active mod, thereafter two new mods were elected and things got better. Now, its the case of sceptics dominating the site nothing else. You yourself was away from the site for years so you obviously can't know what was going on here. @srimannarayanakv

Comment: I made my observation based on my experience. You may not be having that experience.  I may be away from the site for years, but I am not naive in understanding things @Rickross

Comment: Why I can't have the experience? I am 4 years old and never ever off from the site. You are not even close as how active I was. You are not here for many years.So what made you assume that I don't have understanding and experience?@srimannarayanakv

Comment: You may be having different view.  I am having different opinion. I don't want to argue further in this regard @Rickross

Comment: That's fine @srimannarayanakv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that the moderator who deleted your post is [soliciting the community's opinions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1808/2995) on cross-religion posts, *after* the fact, the deletion seems unfair.

Also, I don't see any comments from the mod under your post on the main site before he deleted it:

[image]

I think the correct thing to do in this case would be to undelete your question and then lock it until consensus is reached on meta. Or better yet, undelete the question and leave it to the community to decide by voting.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody can guess what fundamental differences you're trying to question on, right?  if you convert this part to be more specific instead of some differences, the question can be undeleted:

> ""But there are some fundamental differences in quality and behavior between these beings according to the Hindu"

Raise a custom flag after updation.

Comment: Question was not closed as unclear. It's closed as off-topic. While there are many questions which compare other religions and Hinduism. Some even asked for flaws, how to refute etc., I even posted a [meta](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1771/5212) what should be done in case of cross religious questions few weeks ago. You can see the response. Looks like we are back to days where 5 users votes and mod private conversation take more weight than meta discussions. There is contradictory actions everywhere. Same type of questions are treated differently.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma moderators decisions is final and within the scope of the site. Again, as I pointed out in yAdRcchika's answer under comment section, any religion which was created in India, can fall very well under the preview of Sanatana Dharma, especially: Jainism and Buddhism.

Comment: @Ubi Sorry, it's not true 100%. But I would agree that Jainism and Buddhism coexisted along with Sanatana Dharma.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto well in modern curriculum of Indian philosophies, you are taught Jainism and Buddhism as comparative studies.Whereas, Abrahamic religions are taught under Western Philosophies [You don't study them with Indian Philosophy]. My claim is based on the contemporary curriculum of Indian University. As SE.Hinduism is academic in nature. So, we have to assume certain tacit ideas. Also, if you can highlight where I am wrong and provide some insight then will be good for me too :)

Comment: @Ubi this thread is not a good place for such discussion because most of the Indians don't know/ don't want to know the history even if you tell them. We  can continue in Hinduism chatroom though. :-)

Comment: @UbiBhatt This is Hinduism SE. Buddhism, Jainism will be treated as other religions. This has been already said several times. Moderators decision will be final only if they are following scope. They can't leave open one question and close one question even though they ask the same.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma yes you are correct. Question based alone on Buddhism and Jainism should be answered on their respective sites. But, cross faith questions on Hinduism and Buddhism/Jainism is very well welcomed. Yesterday, you argued that cross faith question on Hinduism and islam on halal vegetarian food is okay and today you seems   to have problem? Word halal is not defined in any scriptures of Hinduism. But, Ramayana, Mahabharata & teaching of shiva is very well part of Buddhism/Jainism.

Comment: @UbiBhatt Can you stick to one topic? I am talking about your comments about IIT clubbing Jainism, Buddhism and Hinduism in one course. "Any religion created in India is under Sanatana Dharma". Here we only talk about Hinduism not all religions born in India. Why are you always mentioning Halal question? This question is about specific question linked by OP of the question. Please stick to the topic.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma If you want to express your concern on a particular excerpt of my thought, then highlight it and ask for further explanation. Condescending and patronizing tone will not work. You haven't stated it before anywhere that you are concern about this comment of mine: "...IIT clubbing Jainism, Buddhism and Hinduism in one course...". If you have requested further explanation previously, then please point it out.Do you expect me to read your mind?Also, your personal opinion can not supersede Alagappa university & IIT certificate course work. SE are niche sites with academic inclination.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma You seams have opinion on what moderators can do and can't do. If so, then raise a question on meta.hinduism and ask them, not me.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma I bring halal vegetarian argument to make it clear that the word "Halal" is not described in any Hindu scriptures. We need Muslim Scholars/Experts intervention to provide us insight into what word "Halal" actually means. How can you expect Hindu expert to assume the meaning of the word "Halal"? Isn't that outrageous demand?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Whereas, Ramayana/Mahabharat (Mahabharat is ooze of all upanishadas/vedas) are taught in Jainism. Previous Dalai Lamas use to study in Nalanda. Buddha himself is 9th incarnation of Shri Narayana. So, cross faith questions on Hinduism and Buddhism/Jainism are welcomed. Stand alone Qns on Buddhism/Jainism should be asked on their respective sites.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma I haven't accepted your chat request today because yesterday you left chat without intimating. Even though, I requested you to raise your concern, if any. You had no explanation, so you left without saying. Also, this is meta site and question has a tag: discussion. So, we can discuss it here itself.So, others can learn too. I am not against you, but I don't subscribe to your thought on this particular point of "cross faith questions".

Answer (score -1):

The question was correctly deleted. Because this is a Hinduism dominated site, members tend to not have a good knowledge of other religions, and either intentionally or unintentionally misrepresent other religions. This site should serve as a question and answer site about Hinduism. This is not the site to celebrate the supposed superiority of Hinduism over other faiths.

(If one goes back sufficiently into the past, one is sure to come up with one-off examples of inconsistencies in moderation. This is because moderators are also humans and moderation policies also evolve over time. This site not only relies on moderators but also on members for moderation.)

Comment: Then why this answer was allowed on a similar topic? (https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/199/3869)

Comment: It is not my fault or the fault of the moderators or other members here if sub-standard answers get accepted. @srimannarayanakv

Comment: And Why this question was allowed?(https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/1980/3869)

Comment: Meta discussions have more weight than moderator decision taken temporarily or five users closing or reopening at that time. See the comment under [this answer](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/199/3869). Just a link without any other context, no discussion, nothing from a moderator. Imagine such answers written as an answer and their fate.

Comment: @srimannarayanakv pointing to your 1st comment. Let me tell you that under the domain of Sanatana Dharma Jainism and Buddhism are both included. If you go through the syllabus of Allagappa University they have them included in Indian philosophy master course, also, if you happen to get certificate course from IITs humanities department they include Jainism and Bhuddism in course. So, yes, that particular question is very well under our site domain.

Comment: @UbiBhatt: Then why was my question closed? (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/37143/3869).  You are a new comer and do not know the biased attitude of moderators and senior members of this site.  You will understand slowly.

Comment: @srimannarayanakv because that question is **duplicate.** I might be new on SE.Hinduism, but I have spent quite a time on SE.Computer Science, SE.Math, SE.English, etc.

Comment: Don't jump to conclusions Just by seeing the question. Please read comments as well.

Comment: @srimannarayanakv your last comment is direct to me? [You haven't tagged me].

Comment: Yes please @UbiBhatt

Comment: @srimannarayanakv Sir, I have read all your denouncements in form of comments and I have already provided you with explanation. Those questions are live because they belong to Buddhism [or Jainism].These both religions are part of modern contemporary Indian Philosophy. They are taught as comparative studies. You can check Alagappa/IIT certificate course etc. [to name few]. On other hand, Western Philosophy is taught separately and they mainly focus on Abrahamic religions. Ramanaya/Mahabharata are very well taught to Jains as well. Previous Dalai lamas use to study in Nalanda sharing syllabus.

Comment: @srimannarayanakv SE are niche sites [of stackoverflow] with academic tinge. So, moderators scope of assessment is also academic in nature.

Comment: You did not catch my point my friend. Anyways, you will understand what I am saying now, only when you experience it in this site. Good luck @UbiBhatt

Comment: @srimannarayanakv  If you say so, Sir! I can't read your mind. As you requested, I went through your comments and I could infer that you are perplexed with why Buddhism/Jainism cross religion questions are allowed, but cross Abrahamic religions Qns are not allowed [e.g. OP's question got deleted was Abrahamic cross question]. If you have complain about moderator biases, then final decision is left to them. Also, this is a Beta site, it is not full fledged stable site. Have a good day!

Comment: Interesting. The answer says that the site is not to talk about superiority of Hinduism but the user has no qualms in demeaning it through pointed questions such as - https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/37910/do-vedas-smritis-sanction-genocide-of-non-believers-buddhists-etc

Comment: @Carmensandiego How is my question demeaning?

Comment: @yAdRcchika - It does look to me that there is insinuation that Hinduism justified violence. Especially when I look at the bounty placed on this question https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/35255/did-adi-shankara-persecute-buddhists-in-nagarjunakonda  with the following comment "Especially interested in the local legend, if any. Answer need not say whether the claims are true..... " , it seems that fiction is taking over precedence over facts. Will the bounty be provided if the answer is a categorical NO?

Comment: @carmensandiego There is no insinuation. An incident in Shankara vijaya is mentioned as the background for the question. As for the bounty, reputed sources are requested for supporting the answer. Yes, bounty will be awarded even if the answer is a categorical NO, provided that reputed sources are quoted.

Comment: @yAdRcchika - Very well then. For all we know that claim is without basis that no amateur or serious historian has even written anything about it. The question does not cite any such work. Yet such outrageous questions are left hanging on the site

Comment: @carmensandiego A search on the internet shows a claim that A H Longhurst has written about it in his work The Buddhist antiquities of Nagarjunakonda. I am trying to procure this book, since no body has answered the question.